# Spotting the compositions of functions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I'm learning the Chain rule and it's become apparent that being able to spot 2 functions which can be composed into a given function is essential. I would like to know how people are able to do this so quickly? For example, if I were given the function $R(z) = \sqrt{5z-8}$, how could you quickly deduce that this function can be made by $f(g(z))$ if you let $f(z) = \sqrt z$ and $g(z) = 5z - 8$

Comment: Well, I see R(z) = root (something) so I just set f (z)= root (z) and g (z) = something.  Even if you don't see the right one, you can see something.

Comment: Maybe think at how you would evaluate it. Step 1: calculate $5 z - 8$. Step 2: take the square root of the result from step 1. Now write down the functions for each step. That's precisely how function composition works.

Answer (score 2):

Familiarity comes with practice.  Just devote some time to brute repetition of problems and you should be okay.  And with enough repetition you will notice that your outer "shell" function will be one of the following:

A set of parentheses to a power (as in $(1-x)^{19}$), a trigonometric or related function (like the sinh in $\sinh \left (\frac{1}{4x} \right)$, a radical which can also be expressed as a power (like the square root in $\sqrt{5x-2}$), a logarithm (like the $\ln$ in $\ln(\cos(x))$, a base of an exponent (like the $e$ in $e^{x+2}$), etc.  Not much else.  The inner function will be whatever is in the parentheses or inside the argument of the other.